# I have installed .net on Ubuntu 22.04 yet it doesn't recognize the sdk

Tags: application-development, c#

I firstly installed .net sdk 7.0 using `snap`. VSCode didn't recognize it and I added it to the path (don't remember how, creating a symbolic link I think). Still VSCode wouldn't recognize it inside its shell showing me an error. 
Then I removed it to install it again using `apt` and it still didn't work. Now it doesn't even load the `dotnet --version` command as it can't detect the sdk.

[The output of running commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJShh.png)

How do I fix this nightmare of conflicts?

Edit: I ran `sudo ln -s /snap/bin/dotnet /usr/local/bin/dotnet`
and now it recognizes the sdk, but still not in VSCode